# Why is the padding on my section element not working?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a WordPress site and using Bootstrap. I am trying to add padding to my `section`s but it is not working. In the inspector, it has the yellow triangle exclamation beside it and I cannot figure out why. Here is my CSS:

```
#stats {
    padding: 36px auto !important;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<section id="stats">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h4>This is an infographic</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>This is some supporting text</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Is there something in Bootstrap that is keeping this from happening? Here is a screen shot of the inspector:
[image: Screen shot]

Comment: I found a workaround, but I would still like to know why this isn't working. My workaround is adding `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to the child `.container`.

Answer (score 4):

`auto` is not a valid value for the `padding` property. If you want to use `auto`, use `margin`, or stick to `px` values for `padding`.